# This inspection detects code which can not be normally reached

Tags: python, pycharm

I have no idea why this is happening. When i try to return false it says all if statements below have the error

> This inspection detects code which can not be normally reached

I am using pyCharm and I've heard this is a problem w/ pycharm but i cant corroborate others' problem with my own.

```
code = raw_input("Enter your code: ").lower()
begmeter = int(raw_input("Enter your beginning meter: "))
endmeter = int(raw_input("Enter your ending meter: "))

def errors():

if type(begmeter and endmeter < 0):
    print("Please use an integer above 0 for beginning and end meter")
    return False
else:
    return True

if type(begmeter and endmeter != int):
    print("Please use integers for beginning and end meter")
    return False
else:
    return True


if len(begmeter) > 9:
    print("Beginning meter and end meter can have a max digit amount of 9 digits")
    return False
else:
    return True

if len(endmeter) > 9:
    print("Beginning meter and end meter can have a max digit amount of 9 digits")
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Comment: This is because in the very first if statement, all code paths lead to the method being exited, meaning that nothing below it will _ever_ be able to run. We have either returned a 'True', or 'False' at that point. You should simply remove all the useless `else` statements here such that in the event the condition is not met, it will run down the line and check the next condition.

Comment: It is not a problem with PyCharm, it is an error in your code. Your first `if` statement returns either way, so the rest will never run.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statements at the top look a little fishy to me:

```
if type(begmeter and endmeter < 0):
```

That will always be truthy, because you're taking the type of a value.

So your IDE is telling you that the same branch will always be picked, and the rest of your code is unreachable.

And as other commenters mentioned as well, your first `if` statement is complete, so even if the `if` statement wasn't fishy, you'd never get past it because you're returning either `True` or `False` in the first four lines of your function.

Took a stab at rewriting your `errors()` function closer to what I think your intent is. Note that raw_input always returns a string, and it's on you to try to make sense of it as an int:

```
def errors():
    try:
        begmeter_i = int(begmeter)
        endmeter_i = int(begmeter)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please use integers for beginning and end meter")
        return False

    if begmeter_i <= 0 or endmeter_i <= 0:
        print("Please use an integer above 0 for beginning and end meter")
        return False

    if len(begmeter) > 9:
        print("Beginning meter and end meter can have a max digit amount of 9 digits")
        return False

    if len(endmeter) > 9:
        print("Beginning meter and end meter can have a max digit amount of 9 digits")
        return False

    # we got all the way to the end!
    return True
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The only reason i had those else statements was to have a while loop at the end. I wanted it to run only if there were no errors and i wasn't sure how to do it